# why php.ini don't return change?

Tags: yii, php-ini

I change `expose_php=On` to ( `expose_php=Off` _ `expose_php=off` )

But in `phpinfo()` `expose_php` is on !

For install Yii it should be disabled !

`yii/basic/requirements.php => "expose_php"` should be disabled at `php.ini`

> i'm using xampp
>
> the directory i access to php.ini is `G:\xampp\php\php.ini"

Comment: Did you restart you server after editing the php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP as httpd module, you need to restart httpd for change in php.ini to take effect.

Comment: What should i do at last ?

Comment: well, you, as developer, should first find out what httpd is and then restart it on your xamp :)